# Powershell "Import-Csv" with -Encoding does not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, encoding

I'm trying to set up a SQL Server Agent Job that imports some data from a CSV-document into a table using PowerShell.

The script I wrote works perfectly fine in Windows PowerShell ISE.
As soon as I put it into the SQL Server Agent Job, it doesn't work any longer.

It seems like that the SQL Server does not accept the Argument `-Encoding Default` when importing the CSV-Document.

Code:

```
$Document = Import-CSV $path -Delimiter ";" -Header ... -Encoding Default
```

Error Message:

> A job step received an error at line 12 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is '$Document = Import-Csv $path -Delimiter ";" -Header ... -Encoding UTF8'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Encoding'.  '.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.travisgan.com/2013/05/sql-server-agent-job-and-powershell.html) SQL Server 2012 launches PowerShell 2.0. For older versions it's even PowerShell 1.0.

The parameter `-Encoding` was introduced in PowerShell 3.0, so you will not be able to use it. I think you should be able to use `ConvertFrom-Csv` in combination with `Get-Content` instead:

```
Get-Content $path -Encoding Default | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: Thanks! after changing default to String that worked perfectly fine.